# Wget gives me file names such as "index.html?foo=bar", but browser always opens "index.html" file instead

Tags: browser, filenames

I've downloaded site dump with Wget (links are converted) and a lot of files have names like this: `index.html?foo=bar`. The only way i can open them is to directly specify them as browser arguments. When I try to open them by link in other file, the file opened is just `index.html`. I tried this with Firefox, Chromium, Elinks and Lynx. Lynx is the only one, which works correctly, but I can't always use it, because it has *certain problems*. The only solution I can think of is to rename all files and convert all links in them, but it doesn't look like a convenient one.

Is there something I can do to make browsers (preferably Firefox) open these files by links?

UPD: The problem persists only when I try to open file by following link in other file or open it from address bar. So browsers behave like part after `?` is not part of name, but some data for server. Maybe there is an option to escape these characters by default and follow links literally?

Comment: Can you show us the exact wget command used? (Use example.com if you need to hide the hostname )

Comment: I used `wget -mk example.net`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the site you mirrored is handling `.html` in a special way. Normally, this would be static HTML without any server side scripting, which is just passed through as stored on disk by a webserver.

The `?foo=bar` argument has no effect in static HTML. If this works on the live website, it would suggest that `.html` files on that server are actually handled with a script processor.

This results in you having the rendered output of the script using `wget` instead of the script which generated the output. Since you don't have the actual script, output can be different if the scripts output differs given the arguments.

Comment: *"The `?foo=bar` argument has no effect in static HTML"* -- if there's no client side JavaScript that uses it ;-) (That said, the problem is that **files** now have names that include the `?foo=bar` query.)

Comment: The content of files I got is normal. When I copied some files and then applied Perl script to convert links, it worked as intended. There are just too many files with different names.